# How to set new attribute in stdClass in laravel

Tags: laravel, stdclass

I am creating a new stdClass Object and want to assign a array in a key. I am tying

```
    <?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

class TestController extends Controller{
    function test(){
        $dataObj = new \stdClass();
        $dataObj->setAttribute("open",[]);
        $dataObj->open=['name','age'];
        return $dataObj;
    }
}
?>
```

I want a object like

```
{
      'open':[
               'name',
               'age'
      ]
}
```

Comment: whats wrong with `$dataObj->open=['name','age'];` ?

Comment: Call to undefined method stdClass::setAttribute()

Comment: right, remove that line

Comment: Argument 1 passed to Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response::setContent() must be of the type string or null, object given, called in

Comment: if you want JSON you will have to json_encode it

Comment: Where i have to use json_encode

Comment: `$dataObj = new \stdClass();
        $dataObj->open=['name','age'];
        return json_encode($dataObj);`